Creating separate dope sheet table from Blender file? (for importing into Unity)
Noob here who has somehow ended up employed to use Blender to animate a story about a historical figure, which will be turned into an AR experience.
Having created the animation in Blender, I'm now handing the file over to a team of developers who will translate it into Unity.
I've been told that while animating models' rigging in Blender is helpful and can be imported into Unity, importing other animations (animating along a curve or just keyframing A, moving to the model to B and keyframing again) isn't very successful, so they will likely have to recreate what I've done in Blender from 0.
The idea then is that I will write all of this animation info into a dope sheet table so that the developers can more easily recreate the animations in Unity. I.e, they'll have imported all my models into Unity, and can consult the dope sheet to see that at 00:02, Model 1 glides from A and arrives at B at 00:06, instead of having to use (or in conjunction with) my Blender file as their reference.
TLDR: My question is, is there a way I can export Blender's dope sheet / timeline as a separate document? If not, does anyone know of any dope sheet template software?
